# JMH objects outside a method scope

Tags: jmh

I am using JMH. I have 2 methods which I want to benchmark separately. I have one method (method A) that creates an array of objects. I want another method (method B) to use the same array of objects created in method A. Problem is that by the time method A finished running, the array content no longer exists outside the method A scope. How do I deal with shared state between methods?

Comment: Do you really need the dependency between the two methods? You could use @Setup to create an array for method b. This sample could help: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/39ed8b3c11ce/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_05_StateFixtures.java

Comment: Yes I'm aware of this option but I need to benchmark a method that serialize an array of objects and I want to benchmark separately a method that takes that array of objects and deserialize it. Thanks in advance

Comment: So what about serializing the objects in the @Setup? I don't really get your point here. Maybe it helps if you show some code.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `@Setup` block which creates a collection of instances that you can use for serialization/deserialization. This `@Setup` block will have to do two things; create the objects that you want to serialize, *and* the serialized versions of the same.

What you then do is write your test `methodA` that performs serialization across all the objects (and compares them against the known good serialized fields) and then have the second test `methodB` that performs the deserialization of the objects and compares them with the known good values.

In essence you shouldn't have setup code in your test methods, and you shouldn't assume any kind of ordering between them. Have the setup code that you do once in `@Setup` and then only read those values afterwards. Make sure you're returning the values or checking them in some way so that they aren't eliminated by the JIT.